# Doesn't Factor Analysis always overfit on a theoretical basis

Tags: factor-analysis, overfitting

Imagine you have 3 items that measure some "quality", you could take for example a sum score or you can do a factor analysis.

When you use a factor analysis, don't you basically completely overfit when you assign weights and then use these weights in a model, supposing this measure IS a latent variable in a model? You're practically saying "the latent variable is some kind of "optimal" factor solution (based on the 3 variables/data), assuming it is completely captured by whatever weights are assigned by this optimal solution"

Since it is latent you cannot be sure how this variable is "actually explained" (perhaps in reality a 4th variable would be needed, or the weights are actually different, however the factor analysis just acts like "yes this is the one"), but it seems a bit weird to choose "the best possible (in terms of combined variance) solution" out of all possible ways to bring 3 variables together into a  latent variable. I'm sure this would be easy to illustrate with Venn diagrams.

I'm sorry this is so terribly written and I'm not better able to explain my worries. I'll try to rewrite it, but please bear with me until then.

Comment: Why PCA in the title but then Factor analysis in the question. To my mind these are not the same thing.

Comment: @GavinSimpson My bad, updated. I guess I just had PCA in mind as factor analysis technique.

Comment: `I'll try to rewrite it`. It's time for you to do it because the question is indeed blurred. I can suppose that one root of your confusion is that you think latent trait (factor) _is_ a (weighted) _collection of_ items. While in fact factor is _one_ hidden variable which loads items at different extent - as being their common essense. _Theoretically_ factor pre-exists items; so when you add "a 4th item" factor does not change (it is we who change and start seeing it better or worse). This is what is different from PCA where component is conceptualized as a combination of items.

Answer (score 1):

This question seems to be about *exploratory* factor analysis (FA).  (Initially principal components analysis was also mentioned, and that method has much more to do with exploratory than with confirmatory FA.)

I disagree that one assumes the latent variable to be "completely captured by whatever weights are assigned" to the observed variables.  Instead, one assumes that the observed variables are imperfect expressions of or indicators of that latent variable.  The extent to which they capture it or cover its domain is testable, though, through other techniques.  These might include (all:  please edit)

- a variety of mostly bivariate validation methods such as those addressing convergent, construct, content, and discriminant validity;
- confirmatory factor analysis/structural equation modeling;
- regression.

Few factor-analytic solutions offer "the last word" on the nature of a latent variable.  In this very subjective art/science, there is almost always some additional var. one might include to more fully flesh out a latent var.  Or some improvement in measurement method for one of the observed vars. that will help it better express some aspect of that latent var.

(Terminology note:  "overfit" is used here to mean, I think, "assume too much."  It has a standard meaning centering on predictive models [not FA models].  This has to do with overreliance on a complex predictive model when a simpler one would do a better job of prediction with a new sample.)

Comment: No, it is in fact about confirmatory factor analysis... When you'd state that one latent variable exists of 3 variables, then you're building the factor and you're obtaining the "best fitting" solution (in terms of variance). Is this realistic at all? I do not think so. Probably sub-optimal weights might reflect the "real" latent variable (whenever we pose a theoretical latent variable / idea, why do we rely on some external factor analysis, rather than stating that the latent variable MUST be, on a theoretical basis, a sum score (or we pose weights ourselves)????

Comment: @Pascal, Did rolando say that factor "exists of 3 variables"? He said `include [more item] to more fully flesh out a latent var` where "flesh out" sooner means "define more concretely". It is in line with when he says `the observed variables are imperfect expressions of or indicators of that latent variable`. Factor is _not_ posed to be a sum score of the observed items. We compute factor or scale score as a (weighted or unweighted) sum of items because we need factor/scale values anyway and a sum is a reasonable approximation to true factor values which we _never know_.